# How to add unique date values of a datetime64[ns] Series object

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, datetime, pandas-groupby, python-datetime

I have a column of type datetime64[ns] (`df.timeframe`).

df has columns `['id', 'timeframe', 'type']`

`df['type']` can be 'A' or 'B'

I want to get the total number of **unique dates** per `df.type == 'A'` and per `df.id`

I tried this:

```
df = df.groupby(['id', 'type']).timeframe.apply(lambda x: x.dt.date()).unique().rename('test').reset_index()
```

But got error:

```
TypeError: 'Series' object is not callable
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `value_counts`:

```
df[df['type']=='A'].assign(timeframe=df['timeframe'].dt.date)
    .value_counts(['id','type','timeframe'], sort=False)
    .reset_index().rename(columns={0:'count'})

  id type  timeframe  count
0  1    A 2022-06-06      2
1  1    A 2022-06-08      1
2  1    A 2022-06-10      2
3  2    A 2022-06-07      1
4  2    A 2022-06-09      1
5  2    A 2022-06-10      1
```

Comment: I tried this but got error: ValueError: cannot reindex on an axis with duplicate labels. Any idea?

Comment: @coderuk Share a representative sample of your data with me and I will take a look.  I had generated my own data to create this answer.

Comment: Include data that causes the error.  Update the question with that and I will make it work.